# How hash and value column are generating automatically in jpa?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is my entity class . I dont know how hash and value column is generating automatically :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_CLIENT_LINKS")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ClientLinks {

    String name;

    String type;

    @EmbeddedId
    String clientId;
}
```

db table  P_CLIENT_LINKS :-

[image]

Comment: How the link generated? Also you use  lombok's `@Data`, you should look at the generated class, it may add those fields?

Comment: BTW `@EmbeddedId` is supposed to be used on embeddables. `String` is not an embeddable

Answer (score 0):

1. those two columns (`hash` & `value`) are currently not mapped to your classes (`ClientLinks`) fields, as fields/member variables with the same name don't exist in your entity class
2. what exactly are you expecting to be stored in the database columns `hash` & `value`? if you add member vars with the same name of those columns (of course type must match also) then the JPA mapping should work fine. but you would still need to programatically set the values by calling the setter-methods of those two properties.